# Distribution of js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, dependency-management

I want to create a js library for helping with jasmine tests. What is the js-way of distributing such library? Node modules? Bower? Both? Something else? What is the industry standard in js world?

Comment: node modules are intended for back-end purposes whilst bower is intended for front-end purposes.

Comment: this question is a well hidden request for an off site resource, which is off topic.

Comment: Npm is the best choice at this time. Bower is slowly becoming obsolete as more and more browser based JS libraries move over to npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[npm](http:///www.npmjs.com) is the *de facto* standard for backend Node-based modules and is rapidly gaining traction for front-end development as well. [bower](http://bower.io/) is very popular for front-end things, although [npm is actively trying to become the front-end standard as well](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging).

This is an opinion question and probably a poor fit for StackOverflow for that reason, but I would say: npm regardless, bower in addition if you're library is on the front end.